# How to perform Aadhaar eKYC Authentication via UIDAI and retrieve user details (Name, DOB, Address) with user permitted and OTP verification done?

Tags: php, php-curl, aadhaar

**Concept** - I am making web portal in which i want to add aadhaar authentication and get user detail( name, dob and address), if user permitted and verifies OTP then only.

**language use** - php, curl

**Simple Example -**
EPFO portal user enter his aadhaar number and check, user receive OTP from UIDAI. if valid then get name, birthdate, addresss, like this simple functionality want to build in PHP.

**Error is -**

Error Number - 6 Could not resolve host: auth.uidai.gov.in; Name or service not known
here

**I refer below link --**

1. https://uidai.gov.in/images/resource/Aadhaar_Authentication_API-2.5_Revision-1_of_January_2022.pdf
2. https://www.uidai.gov.in/en/916-developer-section/data-and-downloads-section/11350-testing-data-and-license-keys.html
3. uidai.gov.in/images/resource/aadhaar_otp_request_api_2_5.pdf
4. Similar functionality already exist in https://unifiedportal-mem.epfindia.gov.in/memberinterface/ -- to verify aadhaar and get his detail once user permitted, i need similar functionality , when user permitted then only get name, DOB, address.

**I tried below code but not work,**

```
 <?php
/** * https://uidai.gov.in/images/resource/Aadhaar_Authentication_API-2.5_Revision-1_of_January_2022.pdf */
$adhar_card_no = "123456789012";
 
function checkurl($adhar_card_no)
{
    $host = "https://auth.uidai.gov.in";
    $version = "2.5";
    $aua = "public";
    $asalk = "MAvSQG0jKTW4XxQc2cI-oXZYxYH-zi7IWmsQY1q3JNLlC8VOWOHYGj8";
    $uid = str_split($adhar_card_no);
    $url =  $host."/".$version."/".$aua."/".$uid[0]."/".$uid[1]."/".$asalk;
    return $url;
}

$request_url = checkurl($adhar_card_no);

function requestDataBuilder($uid)
{
    $encrypted_encoded_session_key = "";
    $encrypted_pid_block = "";
    $sha256_pid_bloc_encrypted_encoded= "";
    $digital_aua_signatrure= "";
  
    $auth_data = [
        "uid" => $uid, //Adhaar Card No.
        "tid" => "", //Terminal Id for registered device else public
        "ac" => "", //10 char unique code, public for testing
        "sa" => "", //max length 10, same as ac possible
        "ver" => 1.6, //Current version
        "txn" => "", //AUA transaction  identifier. max length 50, not U*
        "lk" => "", //Valid License Key, max length 64
    ];
    $uses_data = [ "pi" => "n", "pa" => "n", "pfa" => "n", "bio" => "n", "bt" => "n", "pin" => "n", "otp" => "n" ];
    
    $tkn_data = [
        "type" => "001", //only this option available for now which is mobile no.
        "value" => "9595792282" //Mobile no. 10 digit only no prefix
    ];
    $meta_data = [
        "udc" => "123456477699", //[vendorcode][date of deployment][serial number] max length 20
        "fdc" => "NA", //Fingerprint device code. use NA or NC or given code
        "idc" => "NA", //Iris device  code,  us na or NC
        "pip" => "NA", //Public IP address of the device, or NA
        "lot" => "P", //G -lat long format. p for pincode format
        "lov" => "110025" // value as per G and P- my pin change it
    ];
    $skey_data = [
        "ci" => "", //Public key certificate Identifier --mandatory
        "ki" => "" //This is for advanced use only, --optional
    ];

    $format = '<Auth uid="'.$auth_data['uid'].'" tid ="'.$auth_data['tid'].'" ac="'.$auth_data['ac'].'" sa="'.$auth_data['sa'].'" ver="'.$auth_data['ver'].'" txn="'.$auth_data['txn'].'" lk="'.$auth_data['lk'].'">';
    $format.= '<Uses pi="'.$uses_data['pi'].'" pa="'.$uses_data['pa'].'" pfa="'.$uses_data['pfa'].'" bio="'.$uses_data['bio'].'" bt="'.$uses_data['bt'].'" pin="'.$uses_data['pin'].'" otp="'.$uses_data['otp'].'"/>';
    $format.= '<Tkn type="'.$tkn_data['type'].'" value="'.$tkn_data['value'].'"/>';
    $format.= '<Meta udc="'.$meta_data['udc'].'" fdc="'.$meta_data['fdc'].'" idc="'.$meta_data['idc'].'" pip="'.$meta_data['pip'].'" lot="'.$meta_data['lot'].'" lov="'.$meta_data['lov'].'"/>';
    $format.= '<Skey ci="'.$skey_data['ci'].'" ki="'.$skey_data['ci'].'">'.$encrypted_encoded_session_key.'</Skey>';
    $format.= '<Data type="X">'.$encrypted_pid_block.'</Data>';
    $format.= '<Hmac>'.$sha256_pid_bloc_encrypted_encoded.'</Hmac>';
    $format.= '<Signature>'.$digital_aua_signatrure.'</Signature></Auth>';
    return $format;

}
$request_url = checkurl($adhar_card_no);
$data_to_send = requestDataBuilder($adhar_card_no);
//setting the curl parameters.
$ch = curl_init();
$curl_options = [ CURLOPT_URL => $request_url, CURLOPT_VERBOSE => 1, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0, CURLOPT_POST => 1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-Type: application/xml'), CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data_to_send ];



curl_setopt_array($ch, $curl_options);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
$response = curl_exec($ch);

if (curl_errno($ch)) {
// moving to display page to display curl errors
    echo 'Error Number - '.curl_errno($ch).'<br/>';
    echo curl_error($ch);
    echo '<br/> here'; 
} else {
    
    echo $response;
    print_r($response);

}
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

this code not get any OTP , name, DOB from aadhaar.

please help someone, any suggestion.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255232/discussion-on-question-by-mayur-sancheti-how-to-perform-aadhaar-ekyc-authenticat); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 3):

Refer to this sample code. It has the logic of encrypting the XML body. Just download the staging/testing certificates from the [official documentation.](https://www.uidai.gov.in/en/ecosystem/authentication-devices-documents/developer-section/916-developer-section/data-and-downloads-section.html)

```
<?php
require_once 'xmlseclibs/xmlseclibs.php';
use RobRichards\XMLSecLibs\XMLSecurityDSig;
use RobRichards\XMLSecLibs\XMLSecurityKey;

// certificate file locations
$public_certif = 'uidai_auth_stage.cer';
$stag_sign_file = 'Staging_Signature_PrivateKey.p12';

// set variables
$aadhaar_no = '999999990019';
$api_version = "2.5";
$asa_license_key = "MMxNu7a6589B5x5RahDW-zNP7rhGbZb5HsTRwbi-VVNxkoFmkHGmYKM";
$lk = "MBni88mRNM18dKdiVyDYCuddwXEQpl68dZAGBQ2nsOlGMzC9DkOVL5s";
$ac = "public";
$sa = "public";
$tid = "public";
$txn = "AuthDemoClient:public:".date("Ymdhms");
$ts = date('Y-m-d').'T'.date('H:i:s');

// PID Block
$pid_block='<?xml version="1.0"?><ns2:Pid ts="'.$ts.'" xmlns:ns2="http://www.uidai.gov.in/authentication/uid-auth-request-data/1.0"><ns2:Demo><ns2:Pi ms="E" mv="100" name="Shivshankar Choudhury"/></ns2:Demo></ns2:Pid>';

// generate aes-256 session key
$session_key = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32);


// generate auth xml
$auth_xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Auth uid="'.$aadhaar_no.'" ac="'.$ac.'" lk="'.$lk.'" sa="'.$sa.'" tid="'.$tid.'" txn="'.$txn.'" ver="'.$api_version.'" xmlns="http://www.uidai.gov.in/authentication/uid-auth-request/1.0" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><Uses bio="n" otp="n" pa="n" pfa="n" pi="y" pin="n"/><Meta fdc="NA" idc="NA" lot="P" lov="560094" pip="NA" udc="1122"/><Skey ci="'.certif_expire().'">'.encrypt_session_key($session_key).'</Skey><Data type="X">'.encrypt_pid($pid_block, $session_key).'</Data><Hmac>'.calculate_hmac($pid_block, $session_key).'</Hmac></Auth>';

//echo $auth_xml;
 //die();
// $xml=simplexml_load_string($auth_xml) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
//print_r($xml);

// xmldsig the auth xml
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($auth_xml);
$objDSig = new XMLSecurityDSig();
$objDSig->setCanonicalMethod(XMLSecurityDSig::C14N);
$objDSig->addReference(
    $doc,
    XMLSecurityDSig::SHA256,
    array(
        'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature',
        'http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#'
    ),
    array('force_uri' => true)
);
$objKey = new XMLSecurityKey(XMLSecurityKey::RSA_SHA256, array('type'=>'private'));
openssl_pkcs12_read(file_get_contents($stag_sign_file), $key, "public");
$objKey->loadKey($key["pkey"]);
$objDSig->add509Cert($key["cert"]);
$objDSig->sign($objKey, $doc->documentElement);


// make a request to uidai
$ch = curl_init("http://auth.uidai.gov.in/$api_version/public/".$aadhaar_no[0]."/".$aadhaar_no[0]."/$asa_license_key");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $doc->saveXML());
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  "Accept: application/xml",
  "Content-Type: application/xml"
));
echo "\nRequest XML\n";
echo $doc->saveXML();
echo "\n\n";
echo "Response from UIDAI\n";
echo htmlspecialchars_decode(curl_exec($ch));



function encrypt_pid($pid_block, $session_key)
{
    return encrypt_by_session_key($pid_block, $session_key);
}

function encrypt_by_session_key($data, $session_key)
{
    global $public_certif;
    $fp=fopen($public_certif, "r");
    $pub_key_string=fread($fp,8192);
    openssl_public_encrypt($data, $encrypted_data, $pub_key_string, OPENSSL_PKCS1_PADDING);
    return $encrypted_data;
    }
function generateRandomString($length = 32) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;

}

function calculate_hmac($data, $session_key)
{
    return encrypt_by_session_key(hash('sha256', $data, true), $session_key);
}

function certif_expire()
{
    global $public_certif;
    $certinfo = openssl_x509_parse(file_get_contents($public_certif));
    return date('Ymd', $certinfo['validTo_time_t']);
}

function encrypt_session_key($session_key)
{
    global $public_certif;
    $pub_key = openssl_pkey_get_public(file_get_contents($public_certif));
    $keyData = openssl_pkey_get_details($pub_key);
    openssl_public_encrypt($session_key, $encrypted_session_key, $keyData['key'], OPENSSL_PKCS1_PADDING);
    return base64_encode($encrypted_session_key);
}
```

Comment: but aadhaar ekyc verification already use in various system like EPFO portal , how they getting name, address, DOB once aadhar OTP verified/permitted

Comment: They are not using the testing environment URL on their platform. They must be production URLs and credentials. You can request production credentials and try them.

Comment: how to request production credentials

Comment: I found out that the Aadhar authentication has SSL encryption. **Aadhaar authentication requires the identity data of the resident within the XML (PID block) to be encrypted. AES-256 session key is encrypted using UIDAI's 2048- public key. This page contains all certificates available for the ecosystem.** Do you need help in changing your code to add encryption as well?

Comment: i am also using https: to test

Comment: `how to request production credentials` @MAYURSANCHETI as per section 1.2 of the documentation you shared, you must be registered as an AUA or sub-AUA and connected to the private network, in order to access the production system. Perhaps also now to access the test system you must do the same. And I doubt they will give you production access before you have validated your code in testing. This is not some 2-dollar company API, it's the world's biggest biometric database. Again, **contact UIDAI support** if you are having difficulty accessing their systems.

Comment: You can try to use this script `https://github.com/learn-php-code/Aadhar-Authenticate`. It's working. Just download the certificates and packages needed. I have updated my answer with the actual sample code.

Comment: Warning: require_once(xmlseclibs/xmlseclibs.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in E:\XAMPP\htdocs\Mayur\aadhar api\try.php on line 2

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'xmlseclibs/xmlseclibs.php' (include_path='E:\XAMPP\php\PEAR') in E:\XAMPP\htdocs\Mayur\aadhar api\try.php on line 2    --- error with above link script

Comment: @MAYURSANCHETI https://github.com/robrichards/xmlseclibs . I found it in less than 3 seconds. Please use your initiative and at least do some basic googling when you get a problem.

Comment: You'll need to install this [package](https://github.com/robrichards/xmlseclibs) using [compose.phar](https://getcomposer.org/)

Comment: after adding xmlseclibs folder from https://github.com/robrichards/xmlseclibs    , i got new error Warning: file_get_contents(uidai_auth_stage.cer): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in try.php on line 106

Warning: file_get_contents(uidai_auth_stage.cer): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in try.php on line 113

Warning: openssl_pkey_get_details() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in try.php on line 114

Warning: openssl_public_encrypt(): key parameter is not a valid public key in

Comment: @MAYURSANCHETI try and **think** about what the error means. Do you understand basic PHP? Do you understand basic computing principles? What do _you_  think "No such file" means? And which file is it referring to? What type of file is that? And what did Harsh say in an earlier comment: you need to "download the certificates". Did you actually do that, before just diving in head-first? If you cannot even work this simple thing out on your own, and you need us to tell about about every silly little error, then I'm sorry but you are 100 miles out of your depth trying to do anything with Aaadhar.

Comment: sorry, new error is Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML(): Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding ! Bytes: 0x86 0x11 0xE0 0xBA in Entity, line: 1

Comment: Go to this [link](https://www.uidai.gov.in/en/ecosystem/authentication-devices-documents/developer-section/916-developer-section/data-and-downloads-section.html) and download staging/testing certificates from the 3rd Section.

Comment: i add this certificate from https://www.uidai.gov.in/en/916-developer-section/data-and-downloads-section/11349-uidai-certificate-details.html,  now error is -- Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML(): Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding ! Bytes: 0xE6 0xE2 0x67 0x4D in Entity, line: 1 in try.php on line 38

Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML(): PCDATA invalid Char value 22 in Entity, line: 1 in try.php on line 38

Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML(): PCDATA invalid Char value 17 in Entity, line: 1 in try.php on line 38

Comment: Please uncomment line 31 and share the value of the `$auth_xml` variable.

Comment: Auth xml is MovmGiKjl+ekdlI0TOZ26CraNZX0wN71isTTi+mKkV/RDt0wPFKxtFjVbCmwVD1N6ZOyQlXeNCnhU7x7hsobDs4ON86Fh9JxQDYwnLMVWLiFLIuDQGAUcsUpO3T6BxE3/1HbulgH38oDeCZXnsrBiGSBe7TKdEGAcR2WEGcwjVj2BiTtmbRarPiyNW1gGvqRD6mgQe0s05xk2nRP9Sv9jHXT7AzJl0Pp1H3ZuiLppSQStbcVdELf03oMl1nxKDqry+uO+JayTMzdMVWqfhOzvy2HaYsvH7++yVEtnlPUZJT3XFU08kocHrZP0suLMOwDlbJALMPUKynDlyz91j/Q/A==����0YӔ�Th3R��u��2�rk8Z��࿌���݇Sἷ`aG�@ 8��!��H.͋>NIW��L�������[��W�$7m�rN��<�N�������S���#;}c��4h϶,�|���V���qG� ��Z���6�L�;��@qƽĽ�(Z����j�B���*��/TO�ЙC�v��L�-J�ҝ�������o �,1l� #>/ȺZaԐQ�!�Gi$ 荒�+c�`�`rwN*���OȂ�z�� H;�旫�

Comment: if i reward bounty to harsh , because this answer something helpful but not solve, do i need to accept this answer also.

Comment: I don't think so. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty and see if you agree

Answer (score 2):

Encourage private companies, such as Surepass and Signzy, to provide API gateways.

Given the sensitivity of Aadhar data, the government is not permitting its use for testing purposes in this context.

Although we attempted to use API-Setu, we encountered frequent service disruptions.

Comment: but how surepass, signzy do this, how they get key and api for production from UIDAI

Comment: They have subscribed and partnered with the authorities. They designed their own APIs on top of the data.

Comment: how become partner and after making partner can i sure they API for use

Comment: https://uidai.gov.in/en/ecosystem/authentication-ecosystem/authentication-requesting-agency.html

Comment: any other, i read this page, but not given procedure or link

Comment: @MAYURSANCHETI Try [this](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/ready-guide-become-aua-authentication-user-agency-kyc-chandrasekhar). You could also look [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=aadhar+become+an+aua). Again...try to use some initiative and do basic research!

Comment: i read sandbox also given  API , but there charges are confusing , i talk with customer care they told 2 rs per transaction of OTP verificationn and 999 rs subscription charges . any other API service provider which is low cost but most effective in work